# Changing all the colors in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond, music-notation

In Lilypond I can change the color of one type of object with a line like

`\override Staff.Clef  #'color = #(rgb-color 0.4 0.5 0.6)`

I'd like to have everything in the same (non-default) color, but I neither found a list of all the objects I could color nor did I find a command to change all the colors at once. Could anybody please point me to either?

Answer (score 8):

The [LilyPond Snippet Repository](http://lsr.dsi.unimi.it/LSR/) has a [solution that iterates through the list of objects contained in `all-grob-descriptions`](http://lsr.dsi.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=443):

```
#(define (override-color-for-all-grobs color)
  (lambda (context)
   (let loop ((x all-grob-descriptions))
    (if (not (null? x))
     (let ((grob-name (caar x)))
      (ly:context-pushpop-property context grob-name 'color color)
      (loop (cdr x)))))))

% Example of usage:
\relative c' {
  \applyContext #(override-color-for-all-grobs (x11-color 'blue))
  c4\pp\< d e f
  \grace { g16[( a g fis]) } g1\ff\!
}
```

Note that this will change the color of every graphical object only if you run it in the proper context (`Score`, I think, will generally suffice), so you may need to do the following if you're in the middle of, say, a `Voice` context:

```
\stopStaff
\context Score
\applyContext #(override-color-for-all-grobs (x11-color 'blue))
\startStaff
```

Answer (score 3):

The list of graphical objects you need is at the bottom of [this page](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.15/Documentation/internals/grob_002dinterface). So a simple albeit tedious approach would be to iterate through all those objects you use, e.g.

```
\override Staff.Clef     #'color = #(rgb-color 0.4 0.5 0.6)
\override Staff.NoteHead #'color = #(rgb-color 0.4 0.5 0.6)
\override Staff.Beam     #'color = #(rgb-color 0.4 0.5 0.6)
\override Staff.Slur     #'color = #(rgb-color 0.4 0.5 0.6)
```

etc.

There's probably a much better way but I can't figure it out.  Alternatively, [as has been suggested before](http://old.nabble.com/Change-colors-to-white-on-black-td8222742.html) you could consider doing some post-processing on the output from Lilypond, which may be simpler depending on the tools you have available.

I strongly recommend that you read the excellent documentation, in particular how to navigate the Internals Reference as covered by the [Learning Manual](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.14/Documentation/learning/properties-of-layout-objects) and the [Notation Reference](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.15/Documentation/notation/navigating-the-program-reference)

Also you may obtain a better answer from the [lilypond-user mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/lilypond-user).